# Json GET with Ajax and get specific value from the result

Tags: javascript, php

Hello everyone this is my first post on stackoverflow and sorry for any mistakes. I am working on a wikipedia project and I have a problem. I am able to take the infobox (this part i want only) from the page but I can not take specific values from the result table because the table has no attributes on the result table. I thought if it is possible to find the value that I want based on the right value of the same row (the value with bold font). I can not do anything even though I tried many times.

[image: Example Image]

For example in the image above I want to take the value="Greek" and only this and the only  that I can think is to find the value="Demonym" somehow.
The value="Greek" is dynamic and the value="Demonym" is static.

The code is the above :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style>
            .infobox {
                border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
                border-spacing: 3px;
                background-color: #f8f9fa;
                color: black;
                /* @noflip */
                margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
                padding: 0.2em;
                /* @noflip */
                float: center;
                /* @noflip */
                clear: right;
                font-size: 88%;
                line-height: 1.5em;
            }
            .infobox caption {
                font-size: 125%;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 0.2em;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .infobox td,
            .infobox th {
                vertical-align: top;
                /* @noflip */
                text-align: left;
            }
            .infobox.bordered {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .infobox.bordered td,
            .infobox.bordered th {
                border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
            }
            .infobox.bordered .borderless td,
            .infobox.bordered .borderless th {
                border: 0;
            }

            .infobox.sisterproject {
                width: 20em;
                font-size: 90%;
            }

            .infobox.standard-talk {
                border: 1px solid #c0c090;
                background-color: #f8eaba;
            }
            .infobox.standard-talk.bordered td,
            .infobox.standard-talk.bordered th {
                border: 1px solid #c0c090;
            }

            /* styles for bordered infobox with merged rows */
            .infobox.bordered .mergedtoprow td,
            .infobox.bordered .mergedtoprow th {
                border: 0;
                border-top: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
                /* @noflip */
                border-right: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
            }

            .infobox.bordered .mergedrow td,
            .infobox.bordered .mergedrow th {
                border: 0;
                /* @noflip */
                border-right: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
            }

            /* Styles for geography infoboxes, eg countries,
               country subdivisions, cities, etc.            */
            .infobox.geography {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                line-height: 1.2em;
                font-size: 90%;
            }

            .infobox.geography  td,
            .infobox.geography  th {
                border-top: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
                padding: 0.4em 0.6em 0.4em 0.6em;
            }
            .infobox.geography .mergedtoprow td,
            .infobox.geography .mergedtoprow th {
                border-top: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
                padding: 0.4em 0.6em 0.2em 0.6em;
            }

            .infobox.geography .mergedrow td,
            .infobox.geography .mergedrow th {
                border: 0;
                padding: 0 0.6em 0.2em 0.6em;
            }

            .infobox.geography .mergedbottomrow td,
            .infobox.geography .mergedbottomrow th {
                border-top: 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
                padding: 0 0.6em 0.4em 0.6em;
            }

            .infobox.geography .maptable td,
            .infobox.geography .maptable th {
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <center><div id="result"></div></center>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var searchTerm = "greece";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm + "&redirects&prop=text&callback=?",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
                    var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

                    // remove links as they will not work
                    blurb.find('a').each(function () {
                        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
                    });

                    // remove any references
                    blurb.find('sup').remove();
                    blurb.find('audio').remove();

                    // remove cite error
                    blurb.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
                    $('#result').html($(blurb).find('.infobox'));

                },
                error: function (errorMessage) {
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way would be to use your generated DOM to your advantage. Add this after `$('#result').html($(blurb).find('.infobox'));`. Right before closing the "success" function.

```
$('.infobox th').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Demonym') {
     console.log($(this).next('td').text());
    }
});
```

Basically it looks at all table headings and matches "Demonym" term with the text, and then looks at its immediate neighbor TD element for the text value, in our case returning the "Greek" word.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Works great but what do i have to do if i want to take for example the
the row on population  • 2017 estimate  10,768,477 in order to take the number  10,768,477?